# How to get values from step function array?

Tags: python

I have predicted the values using `estimator.predict_survival_function(data_x_numeric)` here data_x_numeric is the input using model is predicting next 12 months probabilities.

the output look like this,

```
array([StepFunction(x=array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]), y=array([0.9226146 , 0.85142196, 0.79525842, 0.75021333, 0.70922316,
              0.67663527, 0.63892244, 0.60731695, 0.58017129, 0.56296385,
              0.54633596, 0.51253825]), a=1.0, b=0.0)                                                                                              ,
       StepFunction(x=array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]), y=array([0.9697228 , 0.94044844, 0.91626724, 0.89609842, 0.87708375,
              0.86147605, 0.84282215, 0.82665755, 0.81235344, 0.80307069,
              0.7939324 , 0.77481341]), a=1.0, b=0.0)                                                                                              ,
```

I have given output for first 2 users, now questions is how can i access the array. example if i want to access the 3rd value of y=array i.e 0.67663527 for 1st user, 0.86147605 for 2nd user.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> first_user_y_array = output[0].y
> third_value_first_user = first_user_y_array[2]
> ```

Have you tried this why ?